# Parallel structure with "than"

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct? 
1) It's easier to draw than doing sports
2) It's easier to draw than do sports
3) It's easier to draw than to do sports

Comment: What does your research tell you?

Comment: They're all fine, but options 1) and 2) sound better. **“Drawing is easier than doing sports”** is simpler

Answer (score 1):

All of them are correct; '**than**' is used both as a conjunction and as a preposition.

In this case, '**than**' is a *preposition* with a gerund as its object:

> It's easier to draw than doing sports.

Here it is a *conjunction*, which links the infinitives '*to draw*' and '*to do*':

> It's easier to draw than do sports.

Note that '**than**' can be used with bare infinitives (verbs without the word '*to*').